# Passing template function, arguments to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

I have a template function. It takes an argument. From within that function I would like to call thread() on a new function.

I want to pass thread a template function, and pass along the argument that was passed into the first argument.

The type of the value passed to both functions is always the same, it isn't even changed.

code:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename S>
void execute_no_atomic(function<R(vector<T>&, vector<S>&)>& fn, vector<T>& input, vector<S>& output);

template<typename T, typename R, typename S>
void Threadpool::execute_no_atomic(function<R(vector<T>&, vector<S>&)>& fn, vector<T>& input, vector<S>& output)
{
    // wrap the function we passed in into a thread, have each thread use the code below
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) {}
    threads[i] = thread(exec, fn, input, output);   

}

template<typename T, typename R, typename S>
void exec(function<R(vector<T>&, vector<S>&)>& fn, vector<T>& input, vector<S>& output);
```

Comment: Give us an example program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: you don’t need to describe what the code is. You can show us the code.

Comment: I posted the two functions.

Comment: Why do you have a `{}` after the for loop?

Comment: Not any particular reason, just for when i comment out the next line.

Comment: Function templates represent an infinite overload set, you need to chose the particular specialization to be passed. This can be done by wrapping the function call in a functor that simply forwards arguments.

Comment: Can you show me an example of that, or a resource?

Also, the type of the data being passed is the template type of what came in. Is there no way to get the compiler to realize this?

Comment: @user3816764 An object's template arguments need to be known in order for its type to be known. If it's a template, that doesn't tell us anything about what types those template arguments *are*.

Comment: Right, but it calculates the values just fine for execute_no_atomic() function's arguments. And the type is always the same, you pass the same exact values to the next function. So it seems like it should be able to determine it, since, at compile time, it would (could) know the types for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so in reality all I really needed was a template **class** , this way all of my template types would be shared across the different functions.

This solved the issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a function template without specifying a particular specialization. This is because the template arguments need to be known in order to determine the function type. Instead of passing the function directly, you can supply a wrapper class that simply forwards arguments, a functor in other words:

```
struct exec_wrapper
{
    template <class... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> decltype(exec(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        return exec(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

...
threads[i] = thread(exec_wrapper{}, fn, input, output);
```

C++14 gives us generic lambdas, which are a little more compact, so you can use it this way:

```
auto glambda = [&] (auto&&... args)
{ return exec(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };

threads[i] = thread(glambda, fn, input, output);
```

Comment: auto glambda = [&] (auto&&... args)


I take it this is creating a lambda, but I'm not sure I understand the auto&&... args.

Comment: @user3816764 `auto` is the "generic" part of it. It simply deduces the type of whatever is passed as arguments. `&&` means "deduce to an lvalue or rvalue", it's for perfect forwarding. The `...` means "any number of arguments".

Comment: EDIT: I will put new code into the main post to comment here.

Comment: @user3816764 Maybe your compiler doesn't support the C++14 standard. Try adding `-std=c++14` to your compiler options.

Comment: I get an unrecognized command line option. I'm using g++ 4.8.

Comment: @user3816764 Please don't edit your question for that! That is what the comments section is for. I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: @user3816764 Yes, it seems that your compiler can't compile C++14 code.

Comment: Whoops. Well, I didn't remove anything, just added. How do I comment code in a comment?

Anyways, I compiled with 1y and I get the same error - auto&& contains no 'packs'

Comment: @user3816764 If it's a lot of code then send me a code example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) then send me the link. If you want inline code in the comments then wrap the code in `\`\`` characters.